# Loading in a CSV file as a Map (D3 and JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, dictionary, d3.js

I've looked around JavaScript and D3's documentation, but couldn't find anything that helps me out...

Is it possible to load in a CSV file that looks like so:

```
header, header
string1, string
string2, string
...
stringN, string
```

And store into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)? Ideally using D3's CSV uploaded?

```
d3.csv("demoCSVOne.csv", function(errorOne, one) {
    d3.csv("demoCSVTwo.csv", function(errorTwo, two) {

    // do something

    }
}
```

CSV example

```
String, Integer
one, 2345
two, 34536
three, 24536
```

**For Mark**
I'm trying to achieve this calculation - get an average value for that from multiple CSVs that have been selected. Where a, b, c, etc represent the value for a key:

```
[(a_csv1 + a_csv2 + a_csv3)/3]
[(b_csv1 + b_csv2 + b_csv3)/3]
[(c_csv1 + c_csv2 + c_csv3)/3]
```

These averages would then need to be stored in a new array, a long with the key that the averages represent. I'm aiming for it to look like this:

```
key, average
     a, 123
     b, 456
     c, 789
```

Comment: what about application of `Array.map()`

Comment: Not sure how that would work with the syntax of loading in CSVs... See edit

Comment: The answer to your question is of course, yes, but you don't give us really enough details.  From your CSV, what's your key and what's your value?  Of course, you might have a bit of an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137546).  If you're working in `d3`, the `.csv` method will produce an array of objects and this is usually the preferred data-structure.

Comment: @Mark I've included an example of what my CSV files look like. The CSV files come from a HashMap in Java, so the keys remain the same for each CSV file it produces, only the values change. Once the CSV files have been loaded into D3, I want to take their content and average each of the CSV files values across all of the dimensions of the map (keys). With these new averages pushed to a new map associated with the keys that they averaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.  Note, I just used a JavaScript object as my map, instead of an ES6 Map object.

```
d3.csv('csv1.csv', function(e1, one) {

  d3.csv('csv2.csv', function(e2, two) {

    // our final map
    var aveMap = {};

    // concat the two csv arrays together
    one.concat(two).map((d) => {
      if (!aveMap[d.String]) aveMap[d.String] = {
        values: []
      };
      // build array of values by key
      aveMap[d.String].values.push(+d.Integer);
    });

    // loop and calculate mean
    Object.keys(aveMap).map((k) => {
      aveMap[k].mean = d3.mean(aveMap[k].values);
    });     

  });
});
```

Produces a final data structure as:

```
{
  "one": {
    "values": [
      2345,
      2323
    ],
    "mean": 2334
  },
  "two": {
    "values": [
      34536,
      45456
    ],
    "mean": 39996
  },
  "three": {
    "values": [
      24536,
      56567
    ],
    "mean": 40551.5
  }
}
```

See it running [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bApAlFwbYMP3bVrLOsdx?p=preview).

**Edits for Comments**

Holding the extra values property in memory isn't really making this code slower.   If it's not performant, there's two reasons: you have lots of CSV files or they are huge CSV files.  For performance, I'd switch to something like this:

```
var q = d3.queue();
['csv1.csv', 'csv2.csv'].map((c) => {
  q.defer(d3.csv, c);
});

q.awaitAll(function(d, csvs){
    var arr = d3.merge(csvs),
        aveMap = {};

    arr.map((d,i) => {
      if (!aveMap[d.String]) {
        aveMap[d.String] = {
          sum: 0,
          count: 0
        };
      }
      var obj = aveMap[d.String];
      obj.sum += +d.Integer;
      obj.count += 1;

      if ( obj.count === csvs.length ){
       obj.mean = obj.sum / obj.count;
      }
    });

    console.log(aveMap);
});
```

First, by using `d3.queue`, you are downloading the csv files concurrently instead of doing them one after the next.  Second, you can adjust the input to `.defer` to only download the files the user actually wants.  Third, you'll notice that I'm now calculating the average inside the first loop.  If these are large datasets, you want to minimize the looping over them.  Fourth, I'm now summing as I go.  Of course, this re-factor assumes that each key exists in each csv file once.

Comment: Okay, that's an interesting approach. A few things: Those two CSVs were just an example, the CSVs that will be used will be dependent on what data points the user selects. So, is there a way to make the `.concat` function dynamic? As sometimes the user may select one, two, three, etc CSVs. Is it also possible to have the average map solely the keys and mean values? After playing with it in the console, it's super slow and all i need are they keys and their new values

Comment: Awesome, looks great and makes more sense to me. I just tried it with 6 CSV files and loading the data takes ages, but it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I've just realised that the function your avemap is calling isn't what  i need... I edited the question for you.